# Where after Substring statement not working in Before Update Trigger MySQL

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have this statement in MySQL, BEFORE UPDATE TRIGGER:

```
SET new.password = (SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 10) WHERE.....
```

No matter what I put after WHERE... that its not working. The full thing would be something like this :

```
SET new.password = (SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 10) where new.time >  NOW() + INTERVAL - 2 second;
```

so that would mean that password would only be updated before 2 seconds after its creation, not after.

What I am getting is Syntax Error #1064, does anyone have a clue on what's missing on the statement and why WHERE is not working there?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What is this?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()) FROM 1 FOR 10)...
```

Do you mean:

```
SELECT LEFT(MD5(RAND()), 10) FROM dual WHERE new.time > NOW() - INTERVAL 2 second
```

I would question your use case however.